# Sqlite select coalcesce with the average of two columns of the same table

Tags: android, sqlite, average, coalesce

I want to realize the average of two columns in only one result.

The following code gives me the last record and does not give me the average of the month:

```
public int media_dic_m (String s_anos_media, String sm_dic) {
String s_date = s_anos_media + "-" + sm_dic + "-";
String s_mp = "SELECT (COALESCE(tr_m_b, 0))/(COALESCE(tr_m_b/tr_m_b, 0)) AS media_m FROM bdt_registro WHERE media_m LIKE '_%' AND tr_fecha LIKE '" +s_date+ "_%'";
Cursor c_mp = db.rawQuery(s_mp, null);
int i_m = 0;
if (c_mp.moveToLast()) { 
    i_m = c_mp.getInt (c_mp.getColumnIndex("media_m"));
    Log.d(LOGTAG,"media en dic" + i_m);
}
c_mp.close();
return i_m;
}
```

return last values.

I like return average value.

Example:
id | date | max_m | max_t

1  | 12-12| 100   | 102

2  | 12-24| 0     | 100

Tot|DEC   | 100   | 101

TOTAL MAX_M AND MAX_T AVERAGE DECEMBRE = 100,5 ==> LIKE THIS VALUE

Thank you for the showed interest

Comment: Do you think you could post some simple example data and the expected result.  It isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: id | date | max_m  |  max_t  
1  | 12-12|  100   |  102                                            2  | 12-24|    0   |  100

Comment: example:                                                            id | date | max_m  |  max_t  
1  | 12-12|  100   | 102                                            2  | 12-24|   0    | 100                                         Tot|DEC   |  100   | 101                                            TOTAL MAX_M + MAX_T AVERAGE DECEMBRE = 100,5